# How to change the default operation of the make command?

Tags: compiling, make

I am using the default make command, without a makefile, but I want to add the `-g` flag to the compilation command by default. How can I do that, without a makefile?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but based on these implicit rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules you want to set your $CFLAGS

therefore your solution should be

```
 export CFLAGS='-g'
```

or in case you had already set something in your CFLAGS

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -g"
```

Comment: Uhm, if you just type `make program`, then there is generated a compilation command with only the `-o` flag, like this: `g++ program.cpp -o program`. I want to have it like this: `g++ -g program.cpp -o program`. Without making a makefile. THe make command is working without a makefile, and I don't want to make one.

Comment: @Genie That's exactly what my solution provides: `make bum` produces `gcc bum.c -o bum` and when you perform `export CFLAGS='-g'` it will produce `gcc -g bum.c -o bum` If you use C++, then the variable is CXXFLAGS... I tested it...

Comment: Aha, great, I didn't knew that I had to use CXXflags :)!

Comment: But it isn't consistent is it? After I closed the terminal it is away :(

Comment: Add it to your .bashrc: https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file

Comment: Like what? `$CXXFLAGS = "-g"`?

Comment: Sorry, newbie in this stuff ;)

Comment: .bashrc is script executed at start of every bash session (whenever you open terminal), therefore you enter the same as you would enter manually otherwise. So just add `export CXXFLAGS='-g'`, on a new line of course

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me. Is it right that the file is in /etc/skel?

Comment: No. It is file `~/.bashrc` (just for your everyday user) or `/etc/bash.bashrc` for setting it systemwide. It will be applied only to newly opened terminal, not to terminals opened before the edit

Answer (score 0):

How about, `alias g++='g++ -g'` ?

Comment: He wants to add -g to the compiler, not to make. This just causes: `make: invalid option -- 'g'`